# How to proceed writing commands in max os x terminal if there is " -- INSERT -- " displaying?

Tags: macos, insert, command

How to proceed writing commands in max os x terminal if there is " -- INSERT -- " displaying ?

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [shrani.si](http://shrani.si/f/1c/11h/1gtT8BMv/screen-shot-2012-11-03-a.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not in the terminal - you're in [Vim](http://www.vim.org/) - a text editor. Type ZZ to come out of if you don't want to continue editing. Or have a look at the link for a basic reference on how to use it.

Comment: Thank you! I was in "insert mode" so I pressed escape so I got into command mode and then I wrote ZZ and everything was OK. I find this link also very useful..http://www.radford.edu/~mhtay/CPSC120/VIM_Editor_Commands.htm